# How to get type of custom class from string c#

Tags: c#, parsing, reflection, service

I am trying to use GetType method for my custom class . I have the name of the class as string and i want to get type of it dynamically. I have the same name for two different classes which are located in different directories.

For Example:

MyClass.cs in Folder1:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.Folder1
{
    public class MyClass : IClass
    {
        public void PrintMe()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("I am Folder 1 Class");
        }
    }
}
```

MyClass.cs in Folder2:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.Folder2
{
    public class MyClass : IClass
    {
        public void PrintMe()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("I am Folder 2 Class");
        }
    }
}
```

Namespace is ConsoleApplication1

different classes with the same name are in the Folder1 and Folder2.

I want to get it's type from such a string:

```
var runtimeString = "Folder1.MyClass"
```

There is method mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) named GetType(string fileName)

How can i get type of the file and resolve it from the serviceLocator with type on runtime like:

```
var typeOfMyClass = GetType(runtimeString);    
var instanceOfMyClass = ServiceLocator.Resolve<TypeOfMyClass>();
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand why you need to do all this.

Comment: The namespace of the two `MyClass` classes in your examples are `ConsoleApplication1.Folder1` and `ConsoleApplication1.Folder2`. You appear to want to create an instance of one of those `MyClass` classes based on a string that doesn't contain the `ConsoleApplication1` part, just `Folder1.MyClass` or `Folder2.MyClass`. Is that correct?

Comment: I have different classes with the same name in different locations and i want to use them respect to runtime response. And also i want to use them in the same variable. They also inherit from same interface

Comment: @Filburt Something like this could be useful for a custom implementation of dependency injection.

Comment: Yes David, it is correct

Comment: Have you tried `Type.GetType( "ConsoleApplication1." + folderNameAndClassName );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be describing a need for a factory method, something along the lines of:

```
public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action<IClass>> _factory =
        new Dictionary<string, Action<IClass>>
        {
            ["Folder1.MyClass"] = () => new ConsoleApplication1.Folder1.MyClass(),
            ["Folder2.MyClass"] = () => new ConsoleApplication1.Folder2.MyClass(),
            ...
        };

    public IClass GetClassInstance(string myClassName)
    {
        if (_factory.Contains(myClassName))
        {
            return _factory[myClassName]();
        }
        throw NoSuchClassException(myClassName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Activator.CreateInstance() method to create an object of a class from its name string as below.

Create the Type object:

```
Type type1 = typeof(MyClass);
```

or

```
Type type1 = Type.GetType("MyClass");
```

Create an instance of that type:

```
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following is what you are trying to accomplish:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var runtimeString = "Folder1.MyClass";
        IClass instanceOfMyClass = (IClass)CreateInstance(runtimeString);
        instanceOfMyClass.PrintMe();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static object CreateInstance(string className)
    {
        var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .First(t => t.FullName.EndsWith(className));

        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

Comment: This solution what i was looking for and also it is working good. But factory pattern will be more useful. Thanks.